# How to execute js(scrollLeft) from php?

Tags: javascript, php, html

i have a function to scroll a div like this:

```
function scrTo(id, to)
{
    document.getElementById(id).scrollLeft = to;
}
```

and try to call it via php:

```
echo"<div id='movingtab' style='overflow-x:auto; width:765;'>";
echo"<table>...Some Table Content...</table>";
echo"</div>";
if(isset($_GET['scrl']))
{
    echo"<script type='text/javascript'>";
    echo"scrTo('movingtab', '".$_GET['scrl']."');";
    echo"</script>";
}
```

The idea is to scroll to last position after the content of div changed via ajax, but when the script executed the scroll is back to begining and not back to last scroll position before div content loaded. I've try to call the function via <script onload="">, but still not working. Can anyone help solve my problem?

Comment: In addition to my answer if u post your ajax request code we can help u better.

Answer (score 1):

Probably Should use:

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function() {
     scrTo('movingtab', '".$_GET['scrl']."');
});
</script>";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php if(isset($_GET['scrl'])) { ?>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        function scrTo(id, to){
            document.getElementById(id).scrollLeft = to;
        }
    </script>
<?php } ?>
<div id='movingtab' style='overflow:auto; width:765px; border:1px solid blue;'>
    <table><tr><td>...Some Table Content...</td></tr></table>
</div>
<button id="scroll" onclick="scrTo('movingtab', '<?php echo $_GET['scrl']; ?>')">scrollLeft()</button>
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't include jQuery lib to my project.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is wrong. You should call the function in the callback of your ajax request. This functionality should be done solely in JavaScript. If you are echoing JavaScript from PHP it is most probably the wrong approach.